# How to make a typing effect in vuejs

Tags: animation, vue.js, typing

hello j try to make a Typing effect on vuejs here is my code.

i'm trying to call setTimeout but it's the effect i want.

template:

```
<template>
<div>
    <span class="back" @click="goToMenu"> 戻る</span>
    <div class="img-container" >
        <img v-bind:src="getCharacter.headImage" class="responsive-image">
        <div class="conversation">
            <span class="name">{{getCharacter.name}}</span>
            <p class="text typewriter-text"> {{outputText}}</p>
        </div>
        <button>Start</button>
    </div>
    <Counter ></Counter>
</div>
```

SCRIPT :
    export default {
        name: "Practice",
        methods: {
            outText() {

```
            if (this.inc < this.text1.length) {
                this.outputText += this.text1.charAt(this.inc);
                this.inc ++;
                setTimeout(this.outText() , 100000)

            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.outText()
    },
    data() {
        return {
            text1 :'こんにちは。あなたの日本語聞かせてほしいな！まずは練習！',
            outputText : '',
            inc:0
        }
    }
}
```

css :

```
<style scoped>
.text {
    background-color: #ababab;
    padding: 4%;
    border-radius: 0 14px 14px 14px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: do you have an example of your "typing effect"?

Comment: What's the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This `setTimeout(this.outText()` is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling the `outText` method when you pass it as an argument to `setTimeout`, doing so will call the method immediately, instead you want to pass the method to `setTimeout` so it can be called later after the timeout has elapsed.

Incorrect:

```js
setTimeout(this.outText(), 100000)
```

Correct:

```js
setTimeout(this.outText, 100000)
```

Also 100000ms (100s) is too long of a delay to notice anything.